# How to take a ordered subset from a Pandas multilevel DataFrame

Tags: pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a large table that looks something like this:

[image]

The above figure shows only frontal part of the table.

Now I want to sort the table on the column '201723' in descending order and take only the first 5 rows from the entire table.

I tried the following code:

```
def func(x):
    return x.sort_values(by='201723',ascending=False)[:5]

bcom_hang_tbl.groupby(['h_platformid', 'model']).apply(func)
```

which results in:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is not what I want because h_platformid and model indices are duplicated.

I tried another one like this:

```
def func(x):
    return x.sort_values(by='201723',ascending=False)[:5]

bcom_hang_tbl.groupby(['h_platformid', 'model'], as_index=False).apply(func)
```

And I got a better result:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

But it is still not satisfactory due to the newly added integer index as indicated in red in the above figure.

I finally tried this one:

```
def func(x):
    x = x.sort_values(by='201723',ascending=False)[:5]
    return x.loc[:, 'ld_fwv':]

bcom_hang_tbl.reset_index().groupby(['h_platformid', 'model']).apply(func).loc[:, 'ld_fwv':]
```

Still not working:
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

How could I do it?

@MaxU, Sorry I made a mistake.I'v changed my small sample data to this:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y','Y'], [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5]], names=['M1', 'M2'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(6,5), columns=list('ABCDE'), index=index)

df.groupby('M1').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'A'))
```

Now the result looks like:
[image]

As in the large table example, index M1 is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC we can use [DataFrame.nlargest()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) method:

```
In [56]: df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'A'))
Out[56]:
        A   B   C   D   E
M1 M2
X  5   10  11  12  13  14
   3    5   6   7   8   9
Y  5   25  26  27  28  29
   3   20  21  22  23  24
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But the suggested method duplicates h_platformid and model indices.

Comment: @Royalblue, can you provide a sample data set in text form?

Comment: @Royalblue, could you also post your desired data set, based on provided sample data set?

Comment: MaxU, I added my desired data set based on the sample data set.

Comment: MaxU, I corrected the code that uses the sample data set. As you could see, the index has been duplicated.

Comment: MaxU, I cannot thank you enough. It works perfectly now!

Comment: @Royalblue, glad i could help :)